# Resize JList in a JScrollPane based on values

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

I have a JList in a JScrollPane:

```
JList list = new JList();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list,
                  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                  JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 201,75);
```

I need to resize the JList/JScrollPane based on the values in JList. Etc: If values are long, JList/JScrollPane width is more, and if the values are short the width resizes to match the width.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to resize the JList/JScrollPane based on the values in JList.
>   Etc: If values are long, JList/JScrollPane width is more, and if the
>   values are short the width resizes to match the width

- its about override `JScrollPane.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`, methods for `JScrollPane`,
- and to get longer text from `JList`, then to use

.

```
SwingUtilities.computeStringWidth(JList.getFontMetrics(JList.getFont()), maxStringToComputeTheWidth);
```

- don't to use NullLayout

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour for a JList is to make the list as wide as the largest string in the JList. If this doesn't work for you it is because you are using a null layout and setBounds(). DO NOT use setBounds(). Use a proper layout manager and let the layout manager do its job and keep your code simple.

If you want to manually control the width of the list then you can use:

```
list.setPrototypeCellValue("some string");
```